# Writing text where text cursor is activated(just like on screen keyboard)

Tags: java

The question may be weird. But I am trying to make it understand. I am trying to make an on screen keyboard in java. It should write characters where cursor is activated. Just like, a microsoft word file is opened, with the keyboard I want to write in that word file. May be I am coding in visual studio, i will write code in visual studio by clicking the keys of keyboard. How can I write in other application with my keyboard.Can anyone give me any idea in this? Thanks in advance.
I have made the keyboard layout (alpha & numeric characters) with swing.

Answer (score 3):

You have a series of compound issues, mostly revolving around keyboard focus.

The main problem is, once you click a button in your window, the window because focused and the button becomes the active recipient of keyboard focus, meaning that any attempt you make to send a keystroke any where will end up being consumed by the button you just clicked.

The easiest way around this is to make all the buttons unfocusable, using `JButton#setFocusable` and passing it `false`.

To programmatically send a keystroke to an active window, you can use the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class

For example...

```
Robot bot = new Robot();
bot.setAutoDelay(100); // I find a small delay between events helps a lot...
bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

You may also like to take a look at [`Window#setAlwaysOnTop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29) and [`Window#setFocusableWindowState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setFocusableWindowState%28boolean%29)

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works. But can you please tell me how to do it with bot.mousePress() method because all the characters in my keyboard are all JButtons. They all create ActionListeners.

Comment: What do you mean? There's an example

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Robot class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

This has two methods, keyPress and keyRelease that you must call to imitate the pressing of a key.

This can be called passing in the KeyEvent constant.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```